# How to get facebook access token in winforms

Tags: c#, facebook, winforms, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm new to the facebook c# sdk, and I'm trying to create a program that will post to a page's timeline.

I have been trying to follow [this](http://codesamplez.com/programming/facebook-api-access-token-using-c-sharp), however I'm having difficulty understanding the second code snippet since it makes use of the `Request` class, in `asp.net`. I can't find a way to translate this into WinForms.

(I did have to change the `FacebookAPI` to `FacebookClient`)

How can I achieve the same effect, of redirecting to facebook and receive the `code` to get an access token?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a specific Winforms sample for the facebook SDK available here: [Facebook Sample using Facebook C# SDK with WinForms](https://github.com/wpasternak/facebook-winforms-sample)

> This sample demonstrates the use of Facebook C# SDK v6 as a WinForms
>   sample.
>
> Note: This sample does not necessarily demonstrate the best use but
>   rather features of using Facebook C# SDK on a desktop app. It is
>   always recommended to use asynchronous (XAsync or XTaskAsync) methods
>   rather then the synchronous methods. XTaskAsync methods are preferred
>   over XAsync methods.

Comment: Thanks, it helped a lot. I don't know how I missed it.

Comment: the link is broken in the answer

Comment: @MuhammadSufiyan - found another

Comment: thanks sir, yes found and currently busy in enjoying learning it :) if you could suggest anything extra for me here, that will be great for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just posting to your own page's timeline, the easiest way is probably a PowerShell script using the New-FBPost cmdlet: http://facebookpsmodule.codeplex.com